# Which version of the distributables report viewer is 10.0.0

Tags: microsoft-reporting

I have the error message

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

From everything I read I should install the report viewer on the server.  However I install 2008 and 2010 and neither are version 10 of the given dll.

So which one do I need?  How can I determine this information without installing the other 4?

Comment: What version do you get when installing 2010?

Comment: I forget, but it turned out to be 2010 SP1.  But I am looking for that list of dlls that come in an installation.  Microsoft use to provide those types of list.

Answer (score 0):

I just met this issue and resolved it.

**ISSUE:**
[image]

**SOLUTION:**

Firstly, we cannot find Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.DLL by normal way. This dll file will not appear on any folder if you search it by Windows Explorer. So, you have to find it by using cmd.

Let do like below picture that I captured. Then, you add reference the dll into your project.
[image]